# Find Input Type Controls from Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have Window Application and have one popup dialog(Form) with some input controls(`TextBox`, `ComboBox`) and other controls like PictureBox, Label. My form have two Mode 1) Add or Edit mode 2) View Mode. In View Mode user can only see details and also can copy input value(e.g user can copy `TextBox` value).

If form mode is View then I want to set read only property to true for all Input controls of form with Iterate One by one control of my Forma(using `for each`). But I don't have idea about How can I know particular control is a Input type control. `System.Windows.Forms.Control` does not have ReadOnly property. I found that I can use Enable property for my solution but problem is that user can not copy text value from `TextBox` if `Enable` set to false.

Can any one help me How can I know particular control is a Input type Control.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by _input type Control_? Are checkbox _input type controls_? I only see "dirty" solutions anyway: a) keep an array of the types you consider as _input control_ b) Check if the Control has a `` `Value` property.

Comment: The Forms.Control does not have the ReadOnly property this is a property on a higher level TextBoxBase class

Comment: Yes. CheckBox is a input type controls. I was also thinking to use array of the input controls types.but looking for better solution. I can think your second solution. let me check.

Answer (score 1):

System.Windows.forms.clipboard.clear();
try this.

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you:

```
foreach(Control ctl in form.Controls)
{
  if (ctl is TextBox)
  {    }
  if (ctl is CheckBox)
  {    }
  if (ctl is ComboBox)
  {    }
  /* etc */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `TextBoxBase` could be the `input type Control`:

```
foreach (TextBoxBase txt in this.Controls.OfType<TextBoxBase>())
{
    txt.ReadOnly = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually cycle through all the controls on the form and then assess each by type.  A little bit of work to start with but once in place you can add more controls without having to worry about setting them individually.

```
foreach (Control c in formMain.Controls)
 {
    if(c.GetType()==typeof(ComboBox))
    {
        ComboBox cb = (ComboBox) c;
        //do something
    }
    else if(c.GetType()==typeof(TextBox))
    {
        TextBox t = (TextBox) c;
        t.ReadOnly = true;
    }
 }
```

I also use the same process for setting generic event handlers e.g. saving a control value to settings on text change. So if you create settings with the same name as your control you can put something like this in the event handler ...

```
private void TextBoxTextchanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox t = (TextBox) sender;
    Settings.Default[t.Name] = t.Text;
    Settings.Default.Save();
}
```